# Visual Studio Community for Mac __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ isn't working

Tags: macos, visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

I'm trying to access some files in a directory relative to my F# code. However, I can't get `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` to return anything other than `/`.

[image]

I've managed to use `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` in Visual Studio on Windows, so can't work out what the problem could be.

I'm seeing this whether I type directly into F# Interactive, create a script file and save it somewhere, or create a project.

The workaround I'm using at present is to hardcode the path to the files, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Version number and other info are as follows:
[image]

Update:
1. It works when using F# interactive from a Terminal/Command window

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly Mac-specific, because you can't reproduce the problem on Windows, and I can't reproduce this on a Linux box either. I don't own a Mac so I'm afraid I can't help you solve this, but perhaps adding an `osx` tag might be a good idea to bring more attention from people who do own Macs?

Comment: One other thing, no wait, two other things I thought of to try: what happens if you run F# Interactive from the command prompt instead of from within Visual Studio? And what happens if you install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (which despite the VS name, is a *completely separate* project from Visual Studio) and the Ionide plugin, then try using the F# Interactive environment from within VS Code? Having those two data points might also help narrow down the problem: e.g., if it works in VS Code but not in VS, then it's a problem with VS, not with your F# installation.

Comment: It works with Visual Studio Code and Ionide. I'll try running F# Interactive from a command prompt after work tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commit/b9c62165b4b50ed20791d67cd79797fa0e9a5f5d#diff-e6f2be4791645764dd11980aafeb53c3) and released in versions 7.6.0.947 and 7.5.0.646